# Axon recreating aggregate state not clear

Tags: java, events, aggregate, axon

I am working on my first Axon application and I cant figure out the use of the aggregates. I understand every time a command handler is called, the aggregate is being recreated by all the events, but I dont understand what other usage the recreating of the aggregates could have.

- Like when should I manually recreate an aggregate?
- What is the benefit of the aggregate being recreated every time I call an command?

The way I set up my application,  I use a aggregateview to persist the data I need into the database. So now I feel like the events are just stored in the event store and are only used to recreate the aggregate after I call a command. Is there nothing else I should do with the events being stored and the recreation of the aggregate? Shouldn't I for example recreate the entire aggregate, instead of fetching the aggregateview out of my database by ID to update it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind Event Sourcing your Aggregate, is that these events are the source for **any** model within your system.

Thus, if you create a dedicated Command Model handling the commands like you describe, then this model (which from Axon's perspective is the `@Aggregate(Root)` annotation class) will be sourced from the events it has published.

Additionally, you can introduce **any** type of Query Model you want; a RDBMS view, a Text-Based Search solution (e.g. Elastic), a time series database, you name it. Any of these Query Models are however still part of this same root application your Aggregate resides in. As you have the events as the means to notify others of decisions being made, it comes natural to (re)use those to update all your Query Models as well.

Now, it is perfectly true that you are not inclined to use Event Sourcing for your Aggregates in Axon, which from it's perspective is called a [State-Stored Aggregate](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/implementing-domain-logic/command-handling/state-stored-aggregates). If you do this however, you'll be back at having distinct models in distinct storage mechanism, without a *single source of truth*.

So, to circle back to your question with this added knowledge, I'd state the following:

> Like when should I manually recreate an aggregate?

You are never inclined to recreate the Aggregate as the Command Model, ever, as the framework does this for you. If you have a mirrored Query Model Aggregate, then you would recreate this whenever you have added/removed/changed fields within the model. Or, if you have introduced entirely new models.

> What is the benefit of the aggregate being recreated every time I call an command?

The benefit of recreating it every time, is the assurance that you will be using the latest state always. Even if between release of your application you have added/changed/removed new fields. The `@EventSourcingHandler` annotated methods would simply fill them in, without the need for you to for example write a database script to adjust it on the database level directly.

---

Concluding, the reason for this approach lies entirely within the architectural concepts supported through Axon. You can read up on them on AxonIQ's [Architectural Concepts](https://axoniq.io/resources/architectural-concepts) page if you want; I am sure it will clarify things even further.

Hope this helps you out @Gisrou8! If not, please come back with more questions, I'd gladly like to explain things further.

---

**Update: Further Command Model explanation**

In the comment Gisrou8 placed under my response it becomes apparent that "the unease" with this approach mainly resides in the state of the Aggregate.

As shared in my earlier response, the Aggregate as can be modeled with Axon Framework should be, in an Event Sourced set up, regarded as the Command Model in a CQRS system.

One of the main pillars around the Command Model, is that the **only** state it contains is the state required for decision making logic. To be more specific on the latter, the only state stored in your Aggregate is the state used to decide if a Command Handler should accepts the incoming command and publish an event as a result.

Thus, the sole fields you would introduce in your Aggregate along side the Aggregate Identifier are the fields you need to drive these decisions.
This is what the Command Model is intended for, so do not worry about this point.

To answer any queries within your application, you'd introduce a dedicated Query Model which is updated as a result of the events published by the Command Handlers within the Aggregate. It's this exact segregation which is the strong suit of this model as it allows for better scaling, performance improvements or required team separations, among other non-functional requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! The part i'm struggling with is the fact that I dont use the data inside the aggregate to for example insert into my aggregateview, but I use the data I pass through the commands. So I was wondering if my approuch is wrong, and I have to use the data from the recreated  aggregate instead of the information I pass through my command. It feels like I dont do anything with the latest state of the aggregate at all? I used the food-ordering example provided by Axon as an example to build my application.

Comment: Aaah gotcha there. Definitely one of the weirder points when you first start with a DDD/CQRS/ES system. I'll update my response to clarify this part @Gisrou8

Comment: Ahh I got it now! Thank you!